# Nginx to default to index.php

Tags: nginx

Using raspbian stretch, and have configured a site using:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    # what does this do? listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;
    server_name localhost;
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.  Maybe change?
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    # Causes too many redirects
    #location / {
    #    index index.php;
    #    try_files  / =404;
    #}
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
    # If desired, deny locations: location ~* /(.git|cache|bin|logs|backups|tests)/.*$ { return 403; }
}
```

The out-of-the-box `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` is:

```
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

http://10.120.11.40/index.php works but http://10.120.11.40 and http://10.120.11.40/ do not.

Adding `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;`, however, allows them to work.

Is the default `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` incorrect, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

you can try

```
index index.php index.htm index.html;
```

Comment: Already have `index index.php;`